# LINQ Statement with List<int?> not returning results?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ query;

```
var sites = new List<int?>();
sites.Add(customer.SiteId);

return context.Where<Equipment>(x => sites.Contains(x.SiteId)).ToList();
```

Where the sites list is a list of SiteIds I need to look up. I am currently testing with a simplified singular list. However, if I were to do a look up using an SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM Sites WHERE SiteId = 59;
```

I get data returned, however if I pass in the id 59 to the above statement I get no results returned? Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here please?

Comment: What is `context` here? Is this Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL, something else? Are you able to look at the generated SQL? What happens if you make `sites` a `List<int>` rather than a `List<int?>`?

Comment: You're testing with a simplified list and insert only `59`, this fails already?

Comment: You are not adding data to your  DataContext

Comment: I'd definitely start by using `List<int>` instead because I doubt that passing a `null` value in the list would actually match up with a `null` on the DB side if the SQL generated is `SiteId in (59, null)` but maybe EF is smart enough to make it `SiteId is null || SiteId in (59)`

Comment: @juharr I guess `x.SiteId` is nullable and that is why OP uses `List<int?>`, not because he is going to store nulls there.

Comment: @Evk In which case you'd do `intList.Contains(SiteId.Value)`, no worries about null reference exception here as it's translated to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You have an item in a table called `Sites` with the `SiteId` of 59, yet, you try to load the `Equipment` records from `context` with the `SiteId` of 59 and this does not yield equipments of the given `Sites` record. This means that you have a `Sites` record with the `id` of 59, but no `Equipment` is linked to that site via the id of 59. Run a query to see what are the equipments having the given `SiteID`, like:

```
select *
from Equipments
where SiteId = 59
```